# Troubleshoot Oracle - hung process

Tags: java, database, oracle

I'm trying to understand a problem we're having with a Java process that is hanging.  This process has been running in production for about 4 months and earlier this week it started hanging.  When I look at a thread dump of the process all of the relevant threads (3) have stacks like the following:

```
    "TxnParser_1" prio=6 tid=0x69bd3400 nid=0x2534 runnable [0x6aa2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1070)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:478)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:790)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1039)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:830)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1132)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1687)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1653)
        - locked <0x40e22f88> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement)
        - locked <0x28f8d398> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
        at com.gcg.data.LogParsingInfo.initFromDB(LogParsingInfo.java:262)
        at com.gcg.om.OmQueueEntry.initParseInfoFromDB(OmQueueEntry.java:104)
        at com.gcg.om.GenericQueueEntry.run(GenericQueueEntry.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

There are no threads waiting for locks so the process isn't deadlocked.  These 3 threads that are doing the work are just blocked waiting for a response from Oracle, at least that is what it looks like to me.

Looking at Oracle, when I query v$session, it looks like  one of the connections associated with these threads is currently executing a query, although I can't see the sql.

```
select ... from v$session where ...;
SQL_ADDRESS      SQL_HASH_VALUE SQL_ID        SQL_CHILD_NUMBER SQL_EXEC_START SQL_EXEC_ID PREV_SQL_ADDR    PREV_HASH_VALUE PREV_SQL_ID   PREV_CHILD_NUMBER PREV_EXEC_START PREV_EXEC_ID
---------------- -------------- ------------- ---------------- -------------- ----------- ---------------- --------------- ------------- ----------------- --------------- ------------
              00              0                                                           0000000239F59EE8      1483377872 fqr8pndc6p36h                 5 26-JUL-12           32080545
              00              0                                                           0000000239F59EE8      1483377872 fqr8pndc6p36h                 5 26-JUL-12           32080546
0000000148CABD88     1784444892 a16hxxtp5sxyw                                             0000000239F59EE8      1483377872 fqr8pndc6p36h                 5 26-JUL-12           32080544

select * from v$sql where sql_id = 'a16hxxtp5sxyw';

no rows selected
```

My questions are:

1. Am I correct in my analysis that the process is simply blocked waiting for a response from Oracle?
2. What should I be looking for in Oracle to understand why this process is blocking?

Updated:

Based on the comment regarding looking in DBA_WAITERS and DBA_LOCKS

```
select * from dba_waiters;

no rows selected

select * from dba_locks where BLOCKING_OTHERS <> 'Not Blocking';

no rows selected
```

There were 98 rows in dba_locks but since all are 'Not Blocking' I don't think it is a locking issue?  The process in question has been in this state for over 3 hours so any deadlock would have been detected by now.

I'm of the theory that the Oracle instance is not "healthy", but I'm at a loss as to what to look at.  I have a request in to reboot the Oracle server, but that hasn't been done yet.

Follow-up question:  Is it normal for the v$session to contain a sql_id that doesn't exist in v$sql and if so, under what conditions?

Comment: That's right - my process is bigger than your process. ;)

Comment: Is the process likely to be doing any updates, or is it just querying? If it is updating, might something else be holding a lock on whatever it's trying to do? I'd start by seeing if `DBA_WAITERS` or `DBA_LOCKS` shows anything interesting.

Comment: Blocking isn't the same as deadlocking; the first (e.g. from an uncommitted changes in another session) can hang for a long time, but might be configured to time out eventually; the second ought to be detected by Oracle and cause an error. But neither seems to be the issue here anyway. 3 hours seems a long time for the JDBC connection or listener to not have complained.

Comment: Alex totally agree with you.  Over 4 hours now and everything is still the same.  Really would like to have something concrete to show DBA group.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was solved and the answer was right in the v$session table.  Apparently Oracle sessions can block for reasons other than just locking. Notice the column FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION - it identifies the session that is the root cause of the blocking.
We investigated session 845 and found that the client process (identified by MACHINE and PORT) no longer existed.  The DBA killed session 845 and all returned to normal.

```
SID     SERIAL# STATUS    PROGRAM          TYPE SQL_ID        PREV_SQL_ID    BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS BLOCKING_INSTANCE BLOCKING_SESSION FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS FINAL_BLOCKING_INSTANCE FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION EVENT
------- ------- --------- ---------------- ---- ------------- -------------- ----------------------- ----------------- ---------------- ----------------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------------
 108    22447   ACTIVE    Gcg log parser 1 USER               fqr8pndc6p36h  VALID                   1                 1581             VALID                         1                       845                    library cache: mutex X
 639    40147   ACTIVE    Gcg log parser 3 USER               fqr8pndc6p36h  VALID                   1                 1581             VALID                         1                       845                    library cache: mutex X
 742    34683   ACTIVE    Gcg log parser 2 USER a16hxxtp5sxyw fqr8pndc6p36h  VALID                   1                 1581             VALID                         1                       845                    library cache: mutex X
```

Comment: Could you clarify how you filtered and identified that these three entries are the root cause of blocking? What gave them away? I'm having exactly the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: The 3 entries shown are not the root cause - they are the Oracle sessions from my application that were getting blocked.  If you scroll to the right and look at the columns BLOCKING_SESSION and FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION you'll see that there are SID values there.  When we investigated the SID 845 (FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION) the session was for a client that no longer existed - for some reason Oracle wasn't able to detect that the client process was gone.

Comment: @sceaj - we are currently experiencing this same issue. Your rightly have identified the problem session but its not a root caused. We are also at this stage and the workaround would be to kill the session however we need to understand why Oracle and the client session got out-of-sync. We strongly believe there is some network "blip" which triggered this. While the network team is looking into the underlaying communication issue. We the DEV decided to introduce "read timeout" which make the connection more resilience.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem recently, and used this query find locking/locked sessions in Oracle:

```sql
select 
   inst_id||' '||sid||','||serial# inst_sid_s#, 
   username,
   row_wait_obj#||','||row_wait_block#||','||row_wait_row# obj_lck,
   blocking_session_Status||' '||blocking_instance||','||blocking_session blk_info,
   final_blocking_session_Status||' '||final_blocking_instance||','||final_blocking_session f_blk_info,
   event, 
   seconds_in_wait 
from 
   gv$session 
where 
   lockwait is not null
order by 
   inst_id;
```

Source:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_final_blocking_session_final_blocking_instance.htm