# ResultSet.next() hung while talking to oracle 11.2 using jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

We have a java application that talks to oracle 11.2 using jdbc. We are using oracle-jdbc-7.jar

```
Created-By: 20.12-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Implementation-Title: JDBC
Implementation-Version: 12.1.0.1.0
```

We are also using Statement.setQueryTimeout()

However, every few days, the thread talking to oracle hangs while doing a ResultSet.next().

Code looks like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = createPreparedStatement();
ps.setQueryTimeout(60);

while (true) {
    ps.executeQuery();

    //iterate over the ResultSet doing ResultSet.next() continuously

    //do something with the ResultSet

    //sleep for 1 second.
}
```

Threaddump:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311)
at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:105)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:305)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:426)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:390)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1022)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3590)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:1008)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:972)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:572)
- locked <0x00000000d0873738> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
```

Any ideas on resolving this would be appreciated?

We have tried using openjdk7 and oracle's JDK 7 but it did not help.

Thanks.

Comment: It's very hard to give suggestions based on a stacktrace alone. Posting the Java code that creates the `ResultSet` (and the query) might help solving the problem.

Comment: [Troubleshoot Oracle - hung process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673947/troubleshoot-oracle-hung-process) might be related -- the same error `locked <...> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)` appears in the stack trace.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I think your comment is better than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the blocking session.

```
SELECT
   s.blocking_session, 
   s.sid, 
   s.serial#, 
   s.seconds_in_wait
FROM
   v$session s
WHERE
   blocking_session IS NOT NULL
```

If it is your session, then your query might need optimization. Otherwise something else is causing the issue.

P.S. : I am no SQL expert